# How to modify a particular column in spark?

Tags: dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a dataset and there is a column of the phone number but the numbers are written in 999-999-9999 format. I want to make that into an integer format by removing the '-' and joining them together, converting them into an integer or a bigint. So can someone help me out with how that can be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `regexp_replace` to remove the hyphens and then cast to bigint:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

df2 = df.withColumn('phone_col', F.regexp_replace('phone_col', '-', '').cast('bigint'))
```

Comment: thanks that works.. in case anyone gets error while typecasting to bigint just use long type.